# Creating semantically clean list with headers

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm currently writing out the markup for the below list design.

[image]

I'm thinking of using a definition list `<dl>` rather than a `<ul>` because there are no bullet points, so no CSS to remove bullets. and it's less markup too. Am I thinking in the right way and is there anything else I should be thinking about?

**HTML markup**

```
<aside class="details">

    <dl>
        <dt>Role</dt>
        <dd>UI Design</dd>
        <dd>Frontend-development</dd>
        <dt>Client</dt>
        <dd>Jame Saunders</dd>
        <dt>Year</dt>
        <dd>2016</dd>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Site</a>
    </dl>

</aside>
```

The only problem is the spacing between each `<dt>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I don't think that description list is the correct way to go about this. Description lists are meant to display definitions of items.

EX:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>

</body>
</html>
```

I would suggest using a `<ul>` tag. It works a bit better than the DL and it is using the correct HTML5 style. So I whipped up a JSFiddle to show how it looks using a `<ul>` and make it look almost exactly like the image. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5xnb97s/2/)

I added some CSS:

```
li.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
li {
  color:rgb(50, 255, 231);
}
a.link {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li.link {
  margin-top:5px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

so that it displays EXACTLY like the image, and added some spacing and link styling. Hopefully this works for you and for future refrence about `<dl>` tags, please refer [to the w3schools example.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't go with `<dl>` tags here but rather `<ul>` tags but below i've adjusted the `margin` and `padding` values for `<dl>`tags to get the output you want.

HTML:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Role</dt>
  <dd>UI Design</dd>
  <dd>Frontend-development</dd>
  <dt>Client</dt>
  <dd>Client Name</dd>
  <dt>Year</dt>
  <dd>2016</dd>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Site</a>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dl {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

dt,
dd {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}

dt {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top:10px;
}

dd {
  color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1tgatcs2/